# Search like unicode character with mongodb as ruby language

Tags: ruby, mongodb, unicode, mongoid

I've done this with MongoDB query but can not work, whereas I with mysql then it works. So how do I search for accented characters look like.

```
Company.where({"$or" => [{"contact_name" => "Hương"}]})
```

=> its working

but `Company.where({"$or" => [{"contact_name" => "huong"}]})`

=> it not work

Please help me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

same ploblem

I used nodejs

```
Product.find({name: {$regex: /máy tính/}}) => results
Product.find({name: {$regex: /may tinh/}}) => no result
```